# How to retrieve Install Statistics from the Google Developer's Console?

Tags: json, console, reporting, google-cloud-storage, information-retrieval

I am trying to programmatically retrieve my company's app data from the Google Developer's Console, specifically the daily installs. I have found that Google recommends the gsutil tool to access the data programmatically through the Google Cloud Storage SDK. However, I beleive they charge for this service. I want a free way to programmatically retrieve the data, preferably as a JSON stream to avoid dealing with file downloads.  I have found the "direct reporting" links, but I have problems authenticating when I try to use them, and I also have to do something with the actual files then.

Is there a way to get a JSON version of the data through OAuth2 or something without downloading an Excel file? Has anyone had to do this? Thanks in advance.